# Seeking Web based GIS for viewing only without need to install client side apps?

Tags: software-recommendations, web-gis

First of all I am new to GIS, I have used ArcGIS and QGIS for some basic engineering projects. Mainly I have looked for freely available GIS data online (solar radiation), downloaded the data, generated JPEG images and submitted engineering reports. I have also done some very basic tasks in ArcGIS, like aspect map, slope map, buffer zone, etc.

Here is my problems, I have a server, i want to log in to server via internet using google Chrome browser and accesses the GIS data that is on the server for viewing only!

I have in total 6 layers, and it would be nice to be able to turn the layers on and off.

Think of it as Google Maps, but only a person with a user/pass can log into it and the person can view a number of layers, turn them on and off, zoom in and out, that is it!

It would be nice if I can make a connection between the above layers and OpenStreetMap as well.

Is this possible and how?

Is there a GIS open source software (or commercial software) that allows for such task?

I have been looking at "web based QGIS" but i am very confused and don't think it is what i want.

Note that I **don't** want the client to install any apps on his computer, I want him to only use Google Chrome browser without any addons.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. There are any number of web-based mapping solutions, but providing software recommendations is not what we're about here. It *is* the purpose of [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 2):

You may try [nextgis.com](http://nextgis.com/) - cloud web GIS. If you already have QGIS project, you can publish it in one click using [NextGIS Connect plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/nextgis_connect/). Also, there is [mobile app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nextgis.mobile) to work with your cloud data in a field.

**Note**: Only available on QGIS 2.18.x as nextgis cloud use the same render engine version.

**Second note**: If you need private access to your data via login/password - this functionality not available on free plan.

Instructions available [here](http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngcom/source/toc.html).

Some examples:

1. [Berlin](http://klab.nextgis.com/resource/178/display?base=osm-mapnik&lon=13.4067&lat=52.4968&angle=0&zoom=16&styles=128,139,141,143,145,147,149,151,153,155,157,159,161,163,165,167,169,171,173,175,177&panel=layers)
2. [Borneo](http://borneomapping.nextgis.com/resource/16/display?base=osm-mapnik&lon=116.9601&lat=-0.3175&angle=0&zoom=12&styles=14&panel=layers)
3. [Samarinda](http://grahacenter.nextgis.com/resource/72/display?base=osm-mapnik&lon=117.1538&lat=-0.4980&angle=0&zoom=18&styles=112,108,106,104,102,82,80,110,100,98,96,94,92,90,88,86,8,6,15,10,73,17,114,19)

You can [install](http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngweb/source/sysadmin.html) this software on your own server too.

**Disclosure**: I'm developer at NextGIS.

Comment: Thanks, but an open source software is what i am looking for ;-)

Comment: This is fully open source software. Do you read documentation? Let me point you in NextGIS Web documentation: http://docs.nextgis.com/docs_ngweb/source/quick_tutorial.html

Comment: @DmitryBaryshnikov - no need to be so snarky about it. The fact that NextGIS Web is open source is buried DEEP in the documentation. I spent a few minutes perusing your website and there is no mention of open source. Even Google doesn't find it in the website, only in the docs (on the website.) If you want the world to know the the software is open source, you need to put it someplace people are likely to find it.

Comment: I'm sorry. Unfortunately I could not express this fact more precisely. I don't want to abuse anybody.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty standard web-mapping and it sounds like you want some fairly common WMS/WFS server technology.  There are a lot of options out there for the server-side such a [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/) (other options are available including QGIS as you have discovered and ArcGIS Server)

Client side, tou need to build a website and use some webmapping tech in it such as [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/) or [Leaftlet](https://leafletjs.com/) (again - other options are available).

Your website will need to handle the authentication too with some server-side accounts code.

I've built some big systems exactly like this and used a [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) based stack (with PostGIS and GEoServer serverside and Leaflet for the client interface)) - but again there are many options.

So, 'yes it is definitely possible' is the short answer to your question.  As to the specifics, much will depend on the stack you put together and that could be the a number of different questions.  I've listed one fairly common Open Source approach here with a few pointers to get you thinking.  Once you have decided on your software, you can come back with other more specific requests for help.

Comment: Thanks for reply. A friend will do the web part, i am involved in finding a way for the GIS part, for the server side i will use QGIS as it is open source and i have done some very basic stuff on it, do you have any link to tutorial for QGIS in the field I am working on?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Qgis2web, available as a plug-in to Qgis. When exporting your map, make sure you check the box next to "Add layers list" under "Appearance. If you want an Open Layers basemap under you layers,select "OSM" from the layers list that appears below the map preview.

You say you have a "server". If it's running a web server, you can place your files there. In order to restrict access to the files you will need to edit the .htaccess file (or equivalent) to restrict access to the directory containing your map.

Comment: Please note that the list of basemaps in qgis2web has been removed in from version 3 onwards. You can add OSM tiles to QGIS via the XYZ provider instead.

Comment: I am playing around with QGIS, don't want to brother you guys without giving it a full try, it is just the IT guy is of no help with his task and I think I have to whole thing to him, and I have absolutely no knowledge of server and website building